Tiling Quandary
Mo Demir is a master tiler, but he knew this task would be challenging - his friend, the famous mathematician Roger P. has asked him to tile the new bathroom.  The customer has given him a full plan - it's looks pretty straightforward.  Derek, the apprentice pipes up "Oh boss, I can do this - it's just the same as Mrs Smith's shower down our way what we did last week."
Mo sighed. This was nothing like Mrs Smith's Shower.
"Okay, lad" - he said to Derek - "where's the repeat?"
After testing some stuff out, Derek gave up. The boss was right.
"So what's the rule, boss?  I can't see it?"
"Maybe a good cup of tea can help", replied Mo, "But just the one. This isn't too hard".
Can you help Mo and Derek?


Here is one way of generating this "self similar" pattern:

 

At each step every line segment introduced in the previous step is surrounded by a hexagon.
After two more iterations we can find the sub rectangle shown in the question:

 


@Albert-Lang, rot13[Ornhgvshy vyyhfgengvba. Vs lbh fubj ubj vg eryngrf gb gur gvyvat nobir V jvyy tvir lbh gur nafjre.]

@Konchog That's the best I can do. Btw. no need to obfuscate normal communication. Only spoilers.

I started out with Alex Ravsky's first observation and found the following increasing pattern:

 At each step, I tried to cover the line segments inside the yellow hexagons (which break them into two trapezoids each). It turns out that each step produces a hexagonal lattice whose hexagons are twice the size of the previous step. While the six steps below cover all the line segments that appear in this image, the procedure can be repeated indefinitely on an infinite plane.

Step 1 (thanks to Alex Ravsky):

 

Step 2:

 

Step 3:

 

Step 4:

 

Step 5:

 

Step 6:

 


rot13[Guvf vf nznmvat jbex ohg Nyoreg Ynat'f qrfpevcgvba bs gur ehyr vf zber pbapvfr (ohg gura ur qbrfa'g chg vg vagb pbagrkg, jurer lbh qb_. V'z gbea nf gb jub gb tvir gur nafjre.]

@Konchog thanks!

A partial answer.

 As far as I see, the tiling pattern consists of the regular uniform background and three kinds of hexagons, which differs by the split into two trapeziums, see the picture.

 


 So the next tiling study step is to study how these three kinds of hexagons are placed.
 


 As far as I see, there are the following regularities:


 each color has a rather regular pattern;


 each color short line has the length $1$, $3$, or $7$.


 each odd horizontal row has the same pattern, and similarly for both kinds of diagonal rows.


 more generally, if $n=2^km$, where $m$ is odd, then the pattern of the $n$th row does not depend on $m$.


Sunny! So does that help?

It seems to me that it's recursive, making something along the lines of the Penrose tiling (hence the mention of Roger P. in the puzzle). I couldn't find any mentions of this specific tiling, though.

@Konchog This can be the starting point. Also I added a couple of observations at the end of the answer.

@Deusovi, Grünbaum & Shephard refer to this (and give away the answer to the puzzle) in Exercise 10.1, Q3(a).  It's not normally called 'recursive' in tiling / symmetry.
